# Contract Compile

Tags: remix, dapps

This is my contract I'm trying to compile:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract DepositContract {
    // The amount of time (in hours) that the contract will run for
    uint256 constant DURATION_HOURS = 24;
    // The payout rate (in percentage per hour)
    uint256 constant PAYOUT_RATE = 416666666667;

    // Mapping from user address to their deposit balance
    mapping(address => uint256) public deposits;
    // Array of structs that stores the expiration time and amount for each deposit
    Deposit[] public depositsArray;

     // The total amount of deposits in the contract
    uint256 public totalDeposits;

    // The start time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public startTime;

    // The end time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public endTime;

    // Flag to indicate whether the contract is active
    bool public isActive;

    // Struct that stores the expiration time and amount for a single deposit
    struct Deposit {
        uint256 expiration;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    constructor() public {
        // Set the start and end times of the contract
        startTime = now;
        endTime = startTime + DURATION_HOURS * 3600;

        // Set the contract to be active
        isActive = true;
    }

        // Function to compound the user's deposit in the contract
    function compound() public {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the user has a positive deposit balance
        require(deposits[msg.sender] > 0, "You do not have a positive deposit balance.");

        // Calculate the compounded amount
        uint256 compoundedAmount = deposits[msg.sender] * (1 + PAYOUT_RATE / 100);
        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] = compoundedAmount;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += compoundedAmount;
    }
    
    // Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit amount must be greater than zero.");

        // Update the deposit balance for the user
        deposits[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // Update the total deposits in the contract
        totalDeposits += msg.value;
    }
    // Add a new entry to the depositsArray with the expiration time and amount
      depositsArray.push(Deposit({expiration: now + DURATION_HOURS * 3600,
      amount: msg.value}));
    }

    // Function to withdraw the user's deposit from the contract
    function withdraw() public {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the user has a positive deposit balance
        require(deposits[msg.sender] > 0, "You do not have a positive deposit balance.");

        // Initialize the payout amount
    uint256 payoutAmount = 0;
    // Loop through the depositsArray and calculate the payout amount for each deposit
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < depositsArray.length; i++) {
        // Check that the expiration time has passed for this deposit
        if (depositsArray[i].expiration <= now) {
            // Add the payout amount for this deposit to the total payout amount
            payoutAmount += depositsArray[i].amount * (1 + PAYOUT_RATE / 100);
        }
    }

    // Check that the calculated payout amount is positive
    require(payoutAmount > 0, "There are no deposits available for withdrawal.");
    // Update the deposit balance for the user
    deposits[msg.sender] = 0;
    // Update the total deposits in the contract
    totalDeposits -= payoutAmount;

    // Send the payout amount to the user
    msg.sender.transfer(payoutAmount);
}
    }
```

It gives me this error: contracts/Fantom Fountain.sol:70:25: ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('
depositsArray.push(Deposit({expiration: now + DURATION_HOURS * 3600,
^

Comment: Yes it does @minhhn2910. Thank You.

Comment: @minhhn2910 - please add it as an answer - strong thrust - please accept as best answer if your issue is now resolved.

Comment: Thanks @VX3 for commenting, I think this question can be closed since it's solved. Have a nice day